# Qt, Обработка данных, UI

Tags: qt, qtcreator

Всем привет! Есть программа, которая работает с огромным количеством данных, и обрабатывает их в несколько подходов. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом пользователю можно вывести текущий прогресс обработки данных? Если при их обработке она зависает "Не отвечает".
Самый действенный способ, который я нашел, это между каждым подходом юзать:

```
QApplication::processEvents(); Но при этом, программа может надолго зависнуть.
```

Также пытался создать вторую форму, на которую через слоты/сигналы посылал информацию. С таким подходом вторая форма тоже зависает!

Comment: Например, вынесите работу в другой поток от которого шлите прогресс обработки. Еще есть QProgressDialog, посмотрите пример с ним он очень простой и не требующий создания других потоков: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprogressdialog.html#details

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо за совет, завтра с QProgressDialog попробую поработать, отпишусь об успехах.
Не могли бы немного про потоки в нескольких словах рассказать?

Comment: @gil9red Думаю QThread очень даже подойдет, если хотите, вынесите то что написали в ответ, т.к. нужную информацию я получил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения данной проблемы решил воспользоваться классом QThread. Если говорить просто, то я переношу все вычисления в отдельный поток, из которого сигналами пересылаю процесс обработки на GUI.
  Класс обработки данных:

```
class worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit worker(QObject *parent = 0);
    void setup(QThread &wThread);
public slots:
    void someAction();
}
```

cpp:

```
void worker::setup(QThread &wThread){
    connect(&wThread, SIGNAL(started()), this, SLOT(someAction()));
}
void worker::someAction(){
///
emit progressSignal(int);
///
}
```

Далее объявляю класс и переношу его работу в другой поток:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     QThread cThread;
     worker cWorker;
     cWorker.setup(cThread);
     cWorker.moveToThread(&cThread);

     cThread.start();
}
```

Теперь пользовательский интерфейс не зависает и при этом отображает текущий прогресс работы.

Comment: По завершению всех расчетов, работу потока прекращаю через метод terminate();
Также есть метод quit(); Но по правде, не разбирал их разницу.

Answer (score -1):

Используйте `QFuture QFutureWatcher` и запускайте метод через `QConcurrent::run`

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?